# How to get volume label based on device name using Python

Tags: python, linux, label, volume, mount

I am making something like a list of mounted devices for Linux.

On program startup I parse /etc/mtab for existing mounts. To get notified about new mounts added to the system am using DBus and in message I get there is volume.label property. Is there any way to get volume label based on device name like /dev/sda1 or /dev/sdd?

**Edit:**
After some time I managed to find a solution to this problem. Python `gio` module has a class named VolumeMonitor. So getting the list with nice names and correct icons is simple as iterating through result of `get_mounts()` method:

```
for mount in volume_monitor.get_mounts():
    print mount.get_name(), mount.get_icon()
```

You can also get a list of drives and volumes. You can also connect some signals and update list appropriately. One note though. Volume is the first one to appear in the list and first to trigger its own events, mounts come later. So if you wish to maintain a list of active mounts, listen to `mount-added` and `mount-removed` signals instead of `volume-added` and `volume-removed`.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gio'`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `e2label` command, you can use `blkid` and then parse its output:

```
$ blkid -o value -s LABEL /dev/sda1
/boot
```

Answer (score 1):

The `e2label` command will tell you the volume label when used like this:

```
e2label /dev/sda1
```

Note: this only works for ext2, ext3, or ext4 filesystems.

From Python, you can invoke the command with `os.system` or `Popen`

Comment: I really need more universal solution. Because I am going to handle removable drives so I can get from vfat to ntfs and others.